# Verilog - individual output arrays

Tags: verilog, declaration

This is my first time on stackoverflow.com and new to verilog coding.  I may use some terms  incorrectly so if I do please correct me so I can be clearer in future posts.

I am using an Altera FPGA board where there are 7 LEDG lights which can be triggered on and off.  For my project I am making a BCD adder where LEDG [7] turns on when the BCD value is not 0 - 9.  However, I don't want to declare outputs [6:4].  LEDG[3:0] displays the binary equivalent of the summation of the two inputs.

I thought I could use two separate declaration statements but it tells me that LEDG is already declared which it is.  I then tried to combine it using brackets but it also complained about that.  Is there any way to simplify my code.  Below are examples of what I've tried.

Example 1:

> ```
> module BCD (..., LEDG, ...);
> output reg [3:0] LEDG;
> output reg [7] LEDG;
> endmodule
> ```

Example 2:

```
module BCD (..., LEDG, ...);
output reg ({[3:0], [7]} LEDG);
endmodule
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: Output full width, but set unneeded bits of array to "Z" state?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the Z state is the don't care state?  How do I go about declaring bits of array to "Z"?  Is it as simple as [6:4] LEDG = Z?

Comment: 'X' is unknown and Z is high impedance. http://www.ee.ed.ac.uk/~gerard/Teach/Verilog/manual/DataTypes/tris.html "There is a signal value: z, which is called "high-impedance". This basically means that a node is isolated, that is not driven. It is possible to assign this value to a net.". Z is like "no output" not 0 nor 1. If the pin is LED driver this means LED is turned off (not connected to ground or VCC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible, if you're going to output a bus then you must specify a single contiguous range.

You should just declare an output reg [7:0] if you need to output [7] and [3:0].

You can leave the unused bits undriven, or if that gives a synthesis warning/error then tie them off to 0 or 1 if you don't care about their value (`LEDG[6:4] = 3'b0`).

Answer (score 0):

```
module(...NBCD_FLAG, LEDG...);
output reg [3:0] LEDG;
output wire NBCD_FLAG;
```

In your .qsf file assign LEDG to leds 3-0 on you board 
and NBED_FLAG to led 7.
This way you can use led 6-4 for some other purpose.